# Use a content script to create an element on the page that is invisible to the page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a content script in a Chrome extension. I'd like to inject an element into the page, but I need to do so in such a way that the page is unaware of the injected element at all, i.e. it needs to be completely invisible to the page and only visible within the content script context. The page should not be able to locate the element (even with getElementByID), receive events related to it, or anything.

Is such a thing possible? How would I go about doing that? If it's not, what is the closest thing I can do?

Comment: What is this element? A DOM node? A script? A variable? ... and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Yes, a DOM node (a div). I want to inject it inside another div on the page.

Comment: So the basic thing you want to do is impossible... Sorry. But maybe you can use another strategy that I won't be able to give you ^^.

Comment: [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)

Answer (score 0):

If [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) as mentioned by @Xan doesn't work for you:

The next best thing would depend a lot on what you are trying to do.

A [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) might suit your needs as you could put the data/buttons/etc. you want to display there and the page would not be able to get to it. You could still run a content script to get the data needed from the page.